# Python. Merge multiple Excel files and add a column with the original file's name

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping somebody will be able to tell me why I am doing wrong, please?

My code reads three Excel files: 0122.xls, 0222.xls and 0322.xls and merges them together in a data frame. My problem is that when I create a new column that should contain the original file's name I am expecting to get 0122.xls, 0222.xls and 0322.xls but getting something different and I can't pinpoint what I am doing wrong. USD 1.1 comes from file 0122, USD 1.2 from 0222.xls and file 0322 contains USD 1.3.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

os.chdir('//.../Python/data')
path = '//.../Python/data'
files = os.listdir(path)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=np.r_[0:7], header=0, usecols=['Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 3'])
    df['col4'] = f
    df = df.append(data)  

df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Curr', 'Unnamed: 3': 'USD'})
df = df.drop(df[df.Curr != 'GBP'].index)

df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the for loop you should change

```py
df['col4'] = f
```

to

```py
data['col4'] = f
```

otherwise reasign all of `col4` every iteration of the for loop, hence why it ends up with the name of the final file in every row.